# How do I create a new table based on a with query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes a JSON. I want to get a certain parameter of the JSON and remove the € sign out of this JSON (so I get a numeric value that I can sum).

That's the base query that works:

```
With C as (
SELECT      A.identifier, 
                JSON_VALUE(A.jsonBody,'$.path) as somethingA,
                JSON_VALUE(A.jsonBody,'$.path) as somethingB
FROM table A WITH(NOLOCK)
join table B on (A.identifier = B.identifier)
WHERE A.statement = 'x')

select  C.identifier, 
    replace (C.fieldA, '€','') as TotalA, 
    replace (C.fieldB, '€','') as TotalB
from C)
```

Unfortunately I am now stuck as I want to get the sum of TotalA per identifier.

As described my query works but I want to get the sum per identifier. So I thought I'd be an idea to simply create (create xxx as (query)) but I get an error.

Anyone has an idea on

- how I can improve this query in general (replace + JSON_Value in one commmand?)
- how I can get the TotalA, TotalB amount per identifier?

Comment: Why do you `JOIN` to `B` when `B` isn't ever referenced? Can you provide sample data, and expected results? Why do you use `NOLOCK` against `table` when aliased as `A`, but not when aliased as `B`, making the use completely pointless and more likely to cause data errors.

Comment: `'$.path` should be `'$.path'`

Comment: You are absolutely right; I also added NOLOCK on B and for the next time I'll also ensure that all parameters are correctly written. Thanks! 